# Im integrating stripe as my payment gateway, i want stripe to show payment methods available based upon users country,now it shows US accounts?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am integrating Stripe, but by default, it shows US bank account and cash pay as payment options we don't need that if the user is from any other country, so I want Stripe to take the user choice of country first and then display the available payment options.
i was expecting that user will be able to select his prefered country and then the payment methods available to be shown to the user

Comment: Maybe this is a better question to ask Stripe directly? It's hard for people to help on StackOverflow when you haven't shared any code. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery.
Or
You can force the country entry that the account will be created in by adding e.g. &stripe_user[country]=US to the OAuth URL: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize

Comment: This is for setting the country of a merchant account, which is not the only factor related to the payment method options an end-customer sees and doesn't relate to OP's question about how the end-customer can select their country and see relevant payment methods.